# Se puede hacer un link que ejecute un botón?

Tags: html, jquery, botón, data, enlace

Tengo una pagina de fotos con Botones para filtrar las fotos por etiquetas Data-Tag

```
<ul class="tabs">
                                            <li><a href="#" data-tag="Todas" id="todas" class="button active">Todas</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" data-tag="Barcelona" class="button">Barcelona</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" data-tag="PEC" class="button">PEC</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" data-tag="Tahitiano" class="button">Tahitiano</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" data-tag="Viaje Tahiti" class="button">Viaje Tahiti</a></li>
```

> Etiquetas Tag para filtrar fotos

Quiero poner un enlace en una imagen de otra página y cuando den click en ese enlace, no se muestren todas las fotos y se muestren las fotos como si hubieran hecho click en una etiqueta

ejemplo: Imagen-Link-Barcelona

Se Abre pagina de fotos y se muestran ya filtradas como si hubieran apretado la etiqueta Barcelona.

Como puedo hacer esto?

Es posible hacer un link que ejecute el boton de otra pagina ?

Answer (score 0):

si se puede con Jquery quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) { //selector del link
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $("button").click(); //selector del boton.
});
```

o tambien se puede con trigger:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) { //selector del link
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $("button").trigger('click'); //selector del boton.
});
```

Comment: Perdona, respondi desde otra cuenta.



Gracias por tu pronta respuesta bro, no tengo experiencia en Jquery, este código lo pego en main.js? a que se refiere con selector del boton ? y despues como lo mando llamar en html ? Saludos! –

Answer (score 0):

Pude hacer el link que necesito de esta forma:

```
        <script 
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $('.milink').click(function() {
        document.getElementById("bx").click();
        });
        });
        </script>
       
       <!-- Link que hace click a otro link -->    
       <a href="#" class="milink"><h2>ejemplo</h2></a>
       
       <!-- Link con etiqueta filtrada-->  
       <li><a href="#" data-tag="Barcelona" id="bx" class="button" 
       title="bx">Barcelona</a></li>
```

Comment: Pero al ponerlo en otra página el link no me funciona, como puedo hacer que funcione externo ?